# Vector arithmetic

Tags: vectors

First of all, apologies for all the text; my questions revolve around why some processes are done rather than how.

I have a line going through points (1,1) and (2,3), and I am asked to find its vector equation.

I understand that $\mathbf{r}(t)=\mathbf{b}t+\mathbf{a}$, in the same way a normal function would take the form $y=mx+c$.

I also understand that the first step is to draw a line from the origin to a point (A), and then from that point to the other point (B).  However the exact reasoning behind this, I am not sure about.

![[http://imgur.com/UJq99Tu]](https://imgur.com/UJq99Tu]) 
(I give up trying to figure out how to put in an image...)

I am also unsure about the following process:

$$\mathbf{r}(t)=\mathbf{b}t+\mathbf{a}$$
$$\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{0A}$$

(The $\mathbf{0A}$ in the example has an arrow above it, whereas the $\mathbf{a}$ is denoted by a line under it. I thought they were both simply different ways of representing a vector and that whatever notation you used didn't matter. So I am wondering why they would differentiate between the two in the example I was given.)

This is where I am really lost though:

$$\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{AB}=\mathbf{0B}-\mathbf{A0}$$

I can see how $\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{AB}$, however I don't understand how $\mathbf{AB}=\mathbf{0B}-\mathbf{A0}$

Would someone be able to explain the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Use the image embed button on the toolbar to embed an image, as your image has now been removed and the link is a 404.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what has the origin to do with your original vectors. An idea: put

$$ A=(1,1)\;,\;\; B=(2,3)\implies \vec{AB}=B-A=(1,2)$$

and thus the line you want is just

$$A+t\vec{AB}=(1,1)+t(1,2)=(t+1\,,\,2t+1)\;,\;\;t\in\Bbb R$$

It's now easy to deduce , putting $\;x=t+1\;,\;\;y=2t+1\;$ , that the above line is in fact just $\;y=2x-1\;$ and that it indeed passes through the given points.

Answer (score 0):

What I assume the notation is supposed to look like(roughly) is the following:

$\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{AB}$

This simply means that $\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{AB}$ is the vector $\mathbf{\overline{x}}$ that solves the following equation:

$A+\mathbf{\overline{x}}=B$

We can examine the part where you write that you're lost. I assume it would look something like this(I usually prefer to make a line above a vector to indicate that it really is a vector, but that is usually replaced by bold font in textbooks):

$\mathbf{\overline{b}}=\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{AB}=\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\mathbf{0}B}-\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\mathbf{0}A}$

The vectors $\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\mathbf{0}B}$ and $\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\mathbf{0}A}$ are the vectors $\mathbf{\overline{u}}$ and $\mathbf{\overline{v}}$ that solve the equations
$\mathbf{0}+\mathbf{\overline{u}}=B$ and $\mathbf{0}+\mathbf{\overline{v}}=A$, respectively.

Further, from the notation above, we know that $A+\mathbf{\overline{b}}=B\Leftrightarrow 
\mathbf{0}+\mathbf{\overline{b}}=(B-A)$. Then we get:

$(\mathbf{0}+\mathbf{\overline{u}})-(\mathbf{0}+\mathbf{\overline{v}})=\mathbf{0}+(\mathbf{\overline{u}}-\mathbf{\overline{v}})=(B-A)=\mathbf{0}+\mathbf{\overline{b}}$

Thus, $\mathbf{\overline{b}}=\mathbf{\overline{u}}-\mathbf{\overline{v}}$, or equivalently

$\mathbf{\overline{b}}=\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{AB}=\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\mathbf{0}B}-\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\mathbf{0}A}$.

One could also view the notation as "The difference between the two points $B$ and $A$ written as a vector".

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this figure can be helpful.
[image]

Here $A=(1,1)$ and $B= (2,3)$ are the given points.
The key fact is that:

> to every two points we can associate a vector (i.e. an oriented
>   segment) that has a vertex in one of the two points  and the other
>   vertex on the other point with the rule $\overrightarrow{AB}=(x_B-x_A,y_B-y_A)^T$ .

Note that $\overrightarrow{BA}=(x_A-x_B,y_A-y_B)^T=-\overrightarrow{AB}$.

Chosing as fist point the origin $(0,0)$, to the points $A,B$ are associated the vectors  $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ and $ \overrightarrow{AB}=\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{v}$.
Now you can see from the figure that any point on th stright line passing thorough $A$ and $B$ can be obtained summing to $\mathbf{w}$ ( or to $\mathbf{v}$)  a multple of $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{v}$. E.g. The point $C$ corresponds to the vector $ \overrightarrow{OC}=\mathbf{w}+1\cdot\mathbf{u}$ and $ \overrightarrow{OD}=\mathbf{w}-2\cdot\mathbf{u}$. So you have the general result:

for any point $R$ on the stright line

$$
\overrightarrow{OR}=\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{w}+t\mathbf{u} \quad \forall t\in \mathbb{R}
$$
Note that te points on segment $AB$ are obtained in this case chosing $-1\le t\le 0 $.

In the same way you can write
$$
\overrightarrow{OR}=\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{v}+t\mathbf{u} \quad \forall t\in \mathbb{R}
$$
and in this case the points on the segment are obtained for $0 \le t \le 1$.